# Can byobu (tmux) show a multiline status

Tags: byobu, tmux

With byobu-screen the default status line had two lines. With byobu-tmux however the default status line only has one line. I liked the seperate line with the list of windows, it let me see more than one window title in a smaller terminal window.

Is it possible to have a multi line status while running on tmux?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not easily, no.  Unfortunately, tmux only supports a single status line at a time.  That's a function of tmux, and not byobu.

What you can do, however, is configure multiple status lines and cycle through them using shift-F5.  You'll only be able to see one at a time, but you can cycle through them with a single keystroke.

You can define and customize these in your `~/.byobu/status` file.  Here's a snippet:

```
# Tmux has one status line, with 2 halves for status
# You can have as many tmux right lines below here, and cycle through them using Shift-F5
#tmux_right="network #disk_io custom #entropy raid reboot_required updates_available #apport #services #mail users uptime #ec2_cost #rcs_cost #fan_speed #cpu_temp battery wifi_quality #processes load_average cpu_count cpu_freq memory #swap #disk #whoami #hostname ip_address #time_utc date time"
#tmux_right="#network disk_io #custom entropy #raid #reboot_required #updates_available #apport #services #mail #users #uptime #ec2_cost #rcs_cost fan_speed cpu_temp #battery #wifi_quality #processes #load_average #cpu_count #cpu_freq #memory #swap whoami hostname ip_address #time_utc disk date time"
tmux_left=" logo #distro release #arch"
tmux_right=" network disk_io custom entropy raid reboot_required updates_available #apport #services #mail users uptime #ec2_cost #rcs_cost fan_speed cpu_temp battery wifi_quality #processes load_average cpu_count cpu_freq memory #swap #disk #whoami #hostname ip_address #time_utc date time"
```

Comment: now tmux support multiple status line https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/1171